# What does 'rails new -d' (preconfigure for database) switch actually do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that the -d switch preconfigures the new project for a specific database, and I believe it sets up the `Gemfile` and `database.yml`, but I'm not sure if it does more than that. I can't seem to find information on what it does exactly. Can anyone elaborate or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds the correct Gem to your Gem file, and preconfigures `config/database.yml` with the correct adapter.

For example:

`rails new -d mysql` will add `mysql2` to your Gemfile, and `adapter: mysql2` to your database.yml.

`rails new -d postgresql` will add `pg` to your Gemfile and `adapter: postgresql` to database.yml

There may be addition adapter-specific configuration directives added to database.yml.

There are no other differences in the initial setup. The later differences in behaviour come from the database-specific Gem.